# Eigen Library assigning Matrix's elements?

Tags: c++, matrix, variable-assignment, eigen

I came across the following assigning for a matrix in Eigen Library [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html)

```
Matrix3f m;
m << 1, 2, 3,
     4, 5, 6,
     7, 8, 9;
```

as an alternative way of the boring one (`m(0,0) = 1;` ... etc). My question is any considerations should I pay at attention to for using the first method? because I know any simplifications come at cost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first case, `m(0,0)=1` calls `operator(Index, Index)` and `operator=(const Scalar& s)`, which is probably pretty fast. Whereas `m << 1,2, ...` calls the overloaded `operator<<` and a chain of overloaded comma `operator,(const Scalar& s)`, see the code here: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/CommaInitializer_8h_source.html

I would guess the second initialization is a bit slower, but unless you are initializing huge matrices by hand, it shouldn't make a difference. In any case, you cannot use the comma initialization to initialize in a loop, so the comma form is used only for small matrices (where you can really write the elements by hand).